# SQL Join Tables, Aggregate Column within Range

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have two tables in my database as follows:

```
 event  | id | value
--------------------
   1    | A  |   10
   2    | B  |   10
   3    | C  |   15
   4    | A  |   15
   5    | D  |   20
   6    | B  |   25
```

and

```
id | value | cost
-----------------
 A |   11  |  5
 B |   12  |  5
 A |   13  |  5
 A |   14  |  5
 C |   16  |  5
 D |   35  |  5
```

I want to group on the `event` and `id` columns from Table 1 and then sum the `cost` column from Table 2 for the corresponding `id` if the `value` column in t2 is within a certain range of the `value` column in t1.

E.g., if my range is +3, I want to return:

```
id_event | total
----------------
   A1    |  10    // 2 rows in t2 with id=A and value between 10 and 13, each with cost = 5
   B2    |  5  
   C3    |  5  
   A4    |  0     // For A4, t1 value = 15, no (id=A) entries in t2 with 15 < value <= 18
   D5    |  0  
   B6    |  0
```

I haven't been able to make this work yet... any tips are much appreciated! I'm mostly familiar with MySQL. Eventually I'll have to implement this in MS Access but it would be good to know how to do it in both. Thanks!

---

Edit: this is the code I'm trying. It's only working for those IDs that only appear once in the second table.

```
SELECT t1.id || t1.event as id_ev, 
       (SELECT SUM(t2.cost) WHERE t2.value <= (t1.value +3) 
                                  AND (t2.value >= t1.value)) as total_cost
FROM ind_e LEFT JOIN data
ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id || t2.event;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want by using a conditional case expression inside this aggregate sum function.

With MySQL (or any ANSI SQL compliant database) the query could look like this:

```
select 
    concat(t1.event, t1.id) id_event, 
    sum(case when t2.value between t1.value and t1.value + 3 then t2.cost else 0 end) total
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by concat(t1.event, t1.id)
```

The `concat` should be changed to the string concatenation function used with the specific database you are using.

MS Access uses a slightly different syntax, and I think it should look like this:

```
select 
    t1.event & Cstr(t1.id) id_event, 
    sum(iif(t2.value between t1.value and t1.value + 3, t2.cost,0)) total
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.event & Cstr(t1.id)
```